# ng-view fades in on purpose, but then fades out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, ng-animate

I have this ngView-directive: `<div ng-view="" class="fade"></div>` where i have the following styles applied:

```
.fade.ng-enter { 
  -webkit-transition:0.3s linear all;
  transition:0.3s linear all;
  opacity:0.5;
}

.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

But the problem is that the view fades in, and then fades out automatically, by setting it's opacity to 0. Am i missing something important? I have made this screencast illustrating the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5IUO-ntlOA

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? All seams correct here.

Comment: Bootstrap apparently has a class called .fade, which has an opacity of 0. *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap apparently has a class called .fade, which has an opacity of 0. That was why.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the fix.

```
.fade.ng-enter { 
  -webkit-transition:0.3s linear all;
  transition:0.3s linear all;
  opacity:0.5;
}

.fade.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

ng-enter disappears and only ng-enter-active remains.